# Check whether the request loaded in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebview` where I'm loading a URL from the server. Everything is working well, but the page is loading slowly in the web view. While it is loading, I have to show an activity indicator.

I have done:

```
 NSURL *urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];

 NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStr];

[webView loadRequest:req];
```

I have added an activity indicator like this:

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]init];
activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle=UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;


activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(webView.center.x,webView.center.y - 150, 60, 60);
[webView addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

When do I have to start and stop animating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you will need to implement [UIWebView Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

You can start it in -

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

and can finish in either -

if success -

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

if fail -

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;

}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{



    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.